# How to design a SQL Server table to store redundant and unique data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. I am creating a new SQL Server table to store the prices of different items in different stores. Most of the prices of items will be the same across the different stores except for a few. For example, if there are 100 stores, item A will be $10.00 in 90 stores and $10.50 in 10 stores and so on. This pattern will be different for different items. I am wondering the best way to design the table so that I need not save so many of the redundant rows which are going to be the same information.

Answer (score 1):

```
+----------------------------+
|          PRICELIST         |
+----------------------------+
| ITEM_ID | STORE_ID | price |
+---------|----------|-------+
|   1     |    0     | 100   |
|   2     |    0     | 200   |
|   2     |   10     | 205   |
+----------------------------+
```

Primary key : ITEM_ID + STORE_ID

As STORE_ID is part of the primary key it is mandatory. Value 0 corresponds to "all stores for which no specific price is defined".

If you use the lowest value (that does not exists as a real storeid) for this purpose you can use following query to fetch the price:

```
select * 
FROM PRICE_LIST 
WHERE ITEM_ID = pItemId 
  AND STORE_ID in (0, pStore) 
ORDER BY STORE_ID DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Store & Item table has many to many relation and to resolve many to many relation you have to create a new table which will store information about which product is available on which store

Create a new table (item_store)
Columns

1. ItemId
2. StoreId
3. Price